# Recommended way of creating UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need to create a UITabBar within my UITabBarController that looks like this:
[image]

So the tab bar would have a black background color by default, and then selected tab items would have a white background color and fill up their entire space on the bar. Also, I want to avoid making the whole tab bar items as images. The only image should be a little icon to the left of the tab bar item text as seen above.

What would be the recommended approach to achieving this look? It seems I'll likely need to subclass UITabBarController but guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this library to achieve the effect: https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVTabBarController